# Is it possible to create a webpage with endless infinite scrolling?

Tags: infinite-scroll

I was curious to know if it was possible to create a website with infinite scrolling that was literally infinite--that is, if the user were to theoretically scroll down forever, that content would continuously be displayed. This content would be a repeated image (an image that is shown and then repeated below itself indefinitely as the user scrolls).

Comment: No, browsers will still use some fixed-size data type (e.g. `uint32`) to represent the height of an element, eventually you'll hit that limit.

Comment: But please don't do this - endless-scrolling is a pain when you want to use the scrollbar or create a permalink to content. Good ol' fashioned hyperlink paging works for a reason, just because it isn't sexy doesn't mean it shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thanks. This is an answer along the lines of what I was looking for. Also, I completely agree with you about using the scrollbar and using permalinks--I was just interested to see if it were possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, no. Infinite is a powerful word. However, they could scroll until they crash the browser I suppose:

http://goo.gl/0ZIFlK

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you mind "accepting" it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a way to implement that JSFiddle into a Dreamweaver site? If so, how could you do that? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks! Sure, but I'm not 100% clear on what you mean by "Dreamweaver site". Just include jQuery in your header, and paste all fiddle code into your page.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible if you reach the end of the content, you get the beginning again and again and again...